# InnerJoin com 3 tabelas Mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta que quando eu digitar o nome de um produto, me retorne o código do setor e a imagem associada a esse setor mas meu innerjoin não está funcionando

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
select ID_CORREDOR_PC, IMAGEM_PC, produto.NOME_PRODUTO from procor 
inner join produto on produto.ID_PRODUTOS = procor.ID_PROD_PC
inner join corredor on corredor.ID_CORREDOR = procor.ID_CORREDOR_PC
WHERE produto.NOME_PRODUTO like %'vinho'
```

Segue tabelas:

**Tabela corredores**

[image: tblCorredor]

**Tabela produtos**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela associativa procor** (produto X corredor)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo fazer somente o select retornando o ID do corredor de acordo com o ID que eu disser no WHERE mas não estou conseguindo dizer que meu WHERE é na verdade o nome do produto

Comment: Seria bom reduzir o código a um [MCVE] pode ajudar bastante, e trocar esse monte de imagem por informação textual. Um exempo de como deveria ser o resultado (com os respectivos dados de entrada) talvez ajude a esclarecer qual parte está com o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala lucas, tudo bem?

Acho que é só um erro de sintaxe do seu like.

Troque isso `like %'vinho'` por isso `like "%vinho"`e fala o resultado para gente.

[Sintaxe do like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Cara, era só esse problema mesmo, vou prestar mais atenção
Obrigado!!